# How to list all data in a blend, and how much disk space it's using?

Tags: objects, performance, data-blocks

I have a blend file that I've worked with for a long time, testing and experimenting with things like rigify and almost everything else. I'm trying to clean it up. By removing a lot of mocap actions, it's almost half in size, from 8 to 4.7 Mb.

I though the mesh might use space, but when I delete all my meshes I went from 4.7 Mb to 4.1Mb. The only important thing left now is an armature and it's drivers.

I ended up deleting everything I could, and it's still 2.3 Mb, compared to about 500k for a new empty file.

So what's using all this space? Is there a way to list all data blocks and how much disk space it's using?

The reason I want to clean this up is that I'm preparing a group for export, and don't want slow performance due to crap in the file.